# What happens to asynchronous methods when all object references are removed?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, garbage-collection

What happens to asynchronous methods when all references to the class are removed? Does the object end up living longer than it should (until the asynchronous method completes)? Or will the asynchronous method be canceled? I ask because I have no compiler around to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instance of the object on which you started the async method will be kept alive until the operation completes. It will not be eligible for garbage collection until some thread contains a reference to it. The async API keeps a reference to this object on a thread from the thread pool and it won't be garbage collected until the operation is over. Async methods won't be cancelled by the garbage collector.

Comment: Do you have any sources to confirm this. It seems like the async pattern does not require the object to be around. You call BeginOpertion and get an AsyncResult. It seems like the AsyncResult is what is kept on the thread pool thread but it is not required that the object is kept as well because to get the actual result from the AsyncResult object you call EndRequest on the original object i.e. you provide this object and there is no need to keep it around internally.

Comment: @Stilgar, the AsyncResult has an [AsyncDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.asyncresult.asyncdelegate.aspx) property which itself has a `Target` property keeping the original reference alive.